# Finding the longest and shortest string in an inputted array

Tags: c, max, min, c-strings, strlen

This is my first time using S.O but Im having trouble with my simple program. Im learning C and Im trying to sort an array of 10 strings (that the user inputs) to find the largest and smallest string and print that on screen at the end, as well as the length of the string. My maximum length is running fine however Im having difficulty when trying to find the minimum length, it just keeps saying " The smallest word is '≡■`☻♦' with 4 characters." I have tried to create a nested loop for the minimum length so that it compares each string in the array against the next as well as the minimum that is stored in the minLength variable. I have no clue why these random symbols are appearing and where its getting this from. Any advice would be much appreciated! Thank you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int maxLength = 0;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    int minIndex = 0;
    char word_length[10][20];

    printf("Please type 10 words: --------------------- \n \n");
    /*USER ENTERS 10 WORDS*/
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%s", &word_length[i]);
    }

    /*SEARCH FROM INDEX POINTER 0-10*/
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        /*NEW VARIABLE LENGTH IS UPDATED TO LENGTH OF EACH STRING HELD IN EACH POINTER IN WORD_LENGTH ARRAY*/
        int length1 = strlen(word_length[i]);
        /*IF THE NEW LENGTH IS BIGGER THAN THE PREVIOUS MAXIMUM LENGTH, THE MAXIMUM LENGTH SCORE IS UPDATED*/
        /*THE MAXINDEX VARIABLE KEEPS A RECORD OF WHICH ARRAY POSITION THIS STRING IS HELD IN*/
        if (length1 > maxLength)
        {
            maxLength = length1;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
        /*NEW VARIABLE LENGTH IS UPDATED TO LENGTH OF EACH STRING HELD IN EACH POINTER IN WORD_LENGTH ARRAY*/
        int length2 = strlen(word_length[i]);
        int next_length2 = strlen(word_length[++i]);
        int minLength = strlen(word_length[1]);
        /*IF THE NEW LENGTH IS SMALLER THAN THE PREVIOUS MINIMUM LENGTH, THE MINIMUM LENGTH SCORE IS UPDATED*/
        /*THE MININDEX VARIABLE KEEPS A RECORD OF WHICH ARRAY POSITION THIS STRING IS HELD IN*/
        if (length2 < next_length2)
        {
            if (length2 < minLength)
            {
                minLength = length2;
                minIndex = i;
            }
        }
    }
    
    /*THE BIGGEST WORD IS DISPLAYED ON SCREEN USING THE MAXINDEX POINTER*/
    printf("The biggest word is '%s' with %d characters\n", word_length[maxIndex], maxLength);
    printf("The smallest word is '%s' with %d characters\n", word_length[minIndex], minLength);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please don't tag irrelevant languages - c and c# are _vastly_ different.

Comment: You should not add the ampersand in scanf when reading a string `scanf("%s", word_length[i]);` is the correct way to do it

Answer (score 1):

For starters this call of scanf

```
scanf("%s",&word_length[i]);
```

should be rewritten at least like

```
scanf("%s", word_length[i]);
```

Though it would be safer to write

```
scanf("%19s", word_length[i]);
```

The both for loops like this

```
for (i=0;i<11;i++)
```

use an incorrect condition.

You have to write

```
for ( i=0; i < 10;i++)
```

The variable `minLength` is not declared in the block scope of the function main.

In this the for loop used for searching a string with the minimal length there is used a locally declared variable minLength

```
for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    /*NEW VARIABLE LENGTH IS UPDATED TO LENGTH OF EACH STRING HELD IN EACH POINTER IN WORD_LENGTH ARRAY*/
    int length2 = strlen(word_length[i]);
    int next_length2 = strlen(word_length[++i]);
    int minLength = strlen(word_length[1]);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

There is no need to use two for loops. It is enough to use one loop.

It can look the following way

```
size_t maxIndex = 0;
size_t minIndex = 0;
size_t maxLength = strlen( word_length[0] );
size_t minLength = strlen( word_length[0] );

for ( size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++ )
{
    size_t length = strlen( word_length[i] );

    if ( maxLength < length )
    {
        maxLength = length;
        maxIndex = i;
    }
    else if ( length < minLength )
    {
        minLength = length;
        mibIndex = i;
    }
}

printf("The biggest word is '%s' with %zu characters\n", word_length[maxIndex], maxLength);
printf("The smallest word is '%s' with %zu characters\n", word_length[minIndex], minLength);
```

Comment: Also note Vlad doesn't use word_length[1] as the smallest value to start with; that ignores the 0th element.